# Locate Fermat's point in a triangle using BFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, geometry, breadth-first-search

Given 3 points in a grid, how would you find a point such that sum of distances of this point from all 3 points in minimized. An obvious answer to this problem is Fermat's triangle. I am interested in knowing if we can locate Fermat's point using a breadth first search algorithm in a graph.

```
struct node{
  int Person1X,Person1Y,Person2X,Person2Y,Person3X,Person3Y; //X and Y coordinates of all 3 persons
  int steps;   //sum of distances covered by all 3 person to reach this state
}
```

While doing the BFS we could put a constraint, 
if steps>min(sum of any two edges of the triangle with 3 persons as vertices) return;

```
if(Person1X=Person2X=Person2X)AND(Person1Y=Person2Y=Person3Y) return steps;
```

Comment: What distance metric is used?  If Euclidean, see methods in wikipedia's [Fermat point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) article.  If Manhattan, 3/4 of all triangles have no such point.

Comment: It's Manhattan. Why would 3/4 of all the triangles have no such point?

Comment: I misspoke, due to thinking of a different problem.  Of course for each triangle ABC on a grid there's a grid point F such that AF+BF+CF is minimal in Manhattan distances.  But for 3/4 of all triangles there is no point F where AF=BF=CF in Manhattan distances: Let pqr denote the parities of points ABC. (Point (x,y)'s parity is (x+y)%2.)  pqr is in {000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111} and takes each value with equal probability.  A point that is distance d from an even-parity point cannot be distance d from an odd-parity point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No search is necessary.

Given "triangle" ABC:
SumOfDistances( p ) = dist( A, p ) + dist( B, p ) + dist( C, p )

where dist( q, p ) = |q<sub>x</sub>-p<sub>x</sub>| + |q<sub>y</sub>-p<sub>y</sub>|  *(Manhattan distance)*

you can see that SumOfDistances( p ) = SumOfDistances<sub>x</sub>( p ) + SumOfDistances<sub>y</sub>( p )

So, you can minimize by the distance on the x and y axis independently.

So, the Fermat point's x-coordinate is the median of the 3 given x-coordinates.
The Fermat point's y-coordinate is the median of the 3 given y-coordinates.

Comment: To see why this is correct intuitively, think about what happens to the total distance when you take 1 step away from the Fermat point.

Comment: So, would this mean that the incenter and the fermat point are same?

Comment: Well, the question is using Manhattan distance, not the usual Euclidean geometry. I think an incenter implies that you're thinking about Euclidean geometry.